# Create hourly intervals without regard to day-month-year in R

Tags: r, time, intervals

I have a list of dates as this:

```
"2014-01-20 18:47:09 GMT"
"2014-01-20 18:46:59 GMT"
"2014-01-20 18:46:59 GMT" 
"2014-01-20 18:46:59 GMT" 
"2014-01-20 18:46:41 GMT"
```

I used this code to split the dates in four-hour intervals

```
data.frame(table(cut(datenormord, breaks = "4 hour")))
```

Results are these:

```
2013-07-22 06:00:00  144
2013-07-22 11:00:00  268
2013-07-22 16:00:00  331
2013-07-22 21:00:00  332
```

What I want is to see how many observations there are in each interval of four hours but not taking account of days months and years. For example I would like to see how many observations there are from 00:00 to 04:00 by adding observations of everyday of every year contained in my dataset

For example i want something like this:

```
01:00:00 1230
06:00:00 2430
11:00:00 3230
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try removing the dates from your date using `strftime` then reformatting them to a date, which will just add the current day, year and month to all the datapoints. You can them break and count like you posted.

```
datenormord<-c("2014-01-20 01:47:09 GMT", "2014-01-20 07:46:59 GMT","2014-01-20 13:46:59 GMT" ,"2014-01-20 18:46:59 GMT" ,"2014-01-20 18:46:41 GMT")
datenormord<-strftime(as.POSIXlt(datenormord), format="%H:%M:%S")
datenormord<-as.POSIXlt(datenormord, format="%H:%M:%S")

result<-data.frame(table(cut(datenormord, breaks = "4 hour")))
```

You can remove the date in the final data frame as well:

```
result$Var1<-with(result,format(strftime(Var1,format="%H:%M")))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is precisely what i need!

Comment: @LucaPerinati consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking on the tick icon next to the question.